# Implementing a Scrabble "Solver"

Tags: regex, string, algorithm

I was toying with the idea of making a program which takes the current board of a scrabble or similar word game, and outputs a list of possible moves the player could make given his or her letters. Say we had the following:

```
                C
                Hello
                E
                S
                S
```

This could be a 2D array of characters, or perhaps in a graph structure with edges and vertices (letters). I have a brute force idea of how to deal with this, and I will detail that as follows:

1. You have 5 letters, L_1 to L_5, and wish to receive a list of words and starting/ending positions. Ex. {"WordName", position_i(x,y) and ending at position_j(x,y)}.
2. If we consider just one possible start position, say directly to the left of the last S in CHESS, we consult our dictionary with the expression "?S?...?" and a hash structure of our available letters. I imagine the dictionary checking each word for this form and that the word is composed entirely of S and the hashed characters. This search is O(Dictionary_Length). We can perhaps optimize here, by doing an O(D_L) pass finding only words with the second letter of S and then checking the characters.
3. Now that we found all words that start at that position, we must consider every other legal position... This is two to the left of the last S in chess, then three, then four to the left (We only have 5 letters so more than 5 to the left would be impossible to create in a legal board which connects letters). Then, of course, considering S as the first letter. Then, move up to the first S and repeat. Then for E, before Hello, and before C. Then we consider top down, making words like ?????CHESS?????, or words above e, l, l, or o.  This is a tricky thing to do since we must consider every possible starting point. If three of our letters were "C, O, L" we could go two above the o in hello and go down to make CoOL for instance, and we could calculate the points if we wanted to.

My question is if there is any obvious optimizations or pruning I could do to avoid checking fruitless positions? Obviously there are heuristics, like "If the second letter is not a vowel, there are significantly fewer possible words" which would allow me to create a subset of the dictionary for such cases.

In addition, this is a very simple board, and larger more complex boards will have many many more starting locations. Each scan would theoretically take O(Dict_Len), and we do... worst case, length of average word * num words * starting chars starting locations (one per word letter, per word, for each shift to accomodate some or all of your letters). This seems pretty costly. Anyway, was just an interesting idea and I was curious about any insight! Thanks :)

Comment: Solving crossword is NP-Hard. I strongly believe scrabble will also be.

Comment: Do a Google search on [scrabble dawg]. The problem you pose is well studied.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, yes I see some good info about it Jim, thanks!  Looks like this is no easy problem to tackle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any algorithm to do this exhaustively is going to be very slow (see comments regarding NP-hard , etc.). A heuristic algorithm to find a few simpler matches is certainly possible, but consider how much work it might take to find the right match to turn this:

```
 P     
 U   E
 REFUSALS
 P O T  E
 L O I  M
 E D M  A
     A  N
     T  T
     E  I
        C
        S
```

into this:

```
 P     
 U   E
 REFUSALS
 P O T  E
ALGORITHM
 E D M  A
     A  N
     T  T
     E  I
        C
        S
```

Obviously, even more complicated examples would be possible, with the difficulty becoming exponentially harder...

Comment: I'll accept this and stop here. I figured it would be beyond polynomial, was just curious if there were any clever ways to do it. But right, exhaustive search would be very slow. I think with a combination of using a lot of memory to cache particular dictionary subsets etc. might help but there is no easy solution.